# Add font to FOP through maven

Tags: maven, apache-fop

I have seen that you can add custom fonts to Apache FOP using the config file as explained [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/fonts.html). However, I am not using a local installation of FOP but a maven installation. I can render pdf files correctly, but I don't know how I can define a configuration file through maven.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can do this with the following java code:

```
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
File file = new File("path/to/file/userConfig.xml");
fopFactory.setUserConfig(file);
```